# RxJava Merge without duplicates

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I am kinda new to RxJava and I am trying to implement search function that searches local db and the server. I would like it merge both results and eliminate the duplicates, any ideas ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [distinct operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can merge the local and remote results and use `toMap` to eliminate the duplicates.

Moreover, if you have more requirements, you can use `collect` and `HashSet`(or `HashMap`) which give you more control:

```
    Observable<Integer> local = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4);
    Observable<Integer> remote = Observable.just(1, 3, 5, 7);
    local.mergeWith(remote)
            .collect(() -> new HashSet<Integer>(), (set, v) -> set.add(v))
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```